# Blazor Server: NavigationManager stop page after navigating to a different page

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-6.0

Blazor with a custom menu component having "Page1", "Page2", "Page3, "PageX" menu items.
When clicking "Page1" I navigate to a different page using NavigationManager.

This works all fine.

However when I quickly click "Page1","Page2", or any other combination of 2 or more pages I have a problem that my Page1 loads but directly another Page is loaded because I quickly clicked menu items.
My pages contain async/await methods and here I have the problem for example:

1. quickly click "Page3", click "Page1", click "Page2"
2. Navigation occurs to "Page3"
3. async methods in Page3 kick in (using async/await/events attached/...)
4. Suddenly navigation occurs to "Page1"
5. Blazor app crashed because for example an async task returned data or accesses a component from "Page3", which has been disposed already because we navigate to "Page1"
6. If we are lucky we reached "Page1", but same might happen because a navigation to "Page2" occurs directly

When a navigation occurs, is there a way to "cancel" the current page when navigating to a different page? (E.g. maybe something similar to a CancellationToken ?)

Comment: NavigationManager.NavigateTo - has overload whit navigation options

Answer (score 2):

- What does say "Page3" looks like?
- What are you doing async in the page?
- Are you doing direct DB access in your page/component?

The Blazor App shouldn't crash.  All the pages are components whose lifecycle is managed by the `Renderer`.  They may be removed from the RenderTree before they have completed rendering, but the Renderer will still await the completion of their event cycle before dropping it's reference to them: they will complete their event cycle.

Here's a demo counter for you to quickly click thro and see what happens. Dispose gets called when the component in removed from the RenderTree, but the
lifecycle still completes.

```
@page "/counter"
@using System.Diagnostics

@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

<div>
    Message: @message
</div>
@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private string message = string.Empty;

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
       Debug.WriteLine($"Started Load at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
        message = "Loading";
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        message = "Loaded";
       Debug.WriteLine($"Finished Load at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
         Debug.WriteLine($"Disposed at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    }
}
```